# PlantUML and Graphviz plugin setup PHPstorm

Tags: phpstorm, graphviz, plantuml

I have already setup **PlantUML** plugin in **PhpStorm**.

and I have download **Graphviz 2.36** and install in my machine.

I have searched how to setup **Graphviz** in order to use **PlantUML** to do a **UseCase** in **PhpStorm**, but I can't found any information

Answer (score 7):

It wasn't really clear to me how to install this thing, so here's some instructions with pictures.

First install the plugin:

[image]

Set the ["Graphviz dot executable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917030/how-to-install-pydot-and-graphviz/917033#917033):

[image]

Optionally associate with `.dot` files:

[image]

You have to wrap your code with `@startuml` and `@enduml` for it to do anything, so its not *really* a dot file, but good enough:

[image]

Comment: For me it is not so clear whether we must add graphviz dot executable file in PlantUML Settings? Why do we add .dot file extension in file types? In which situation should we create a diagram with dot extension or puml? Could you please extend your answer?

Comment: @limonik I assume the executable is required and used to do the actual rendering. You *don't* need to add the `.dot` file extension (I said it was optional). Which you use is up to you. I've never used "PlantUML", I just wanted dot support. `.dot` files have better support with other apps, but the `@startuml` kind of invalidates them.

Answer (score 2):

I missed setting the "Environment variable".

http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/graphvizdot.html

After setting it, restart your PHPstorm and it should be fine.