# Can't render component diagram with PlantUML in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, plantuml

I am trying to create a component diagram using the PlantUML plugin for IntelliJ.
I have installed the plugin and worked with it before. However, when I try to render a component diagram, I get an error:

> Cannot find Graphviz

[image]

I've also checked with other diagrams and a sequence diagram is still working just fine.

[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: There is related issue on plugin issue tracker: https://github.com/esteinberg/plantuml4idea/issues/200

Comment: it looks exactly the same but I dont see how he solve the problem. Maybe I need to reinstall Grapgviz? how can I do it?

Answer (score 85):

#### Option 1.

On a mac using Intellij, if Intellij cannot find graphviz, testdot doesn't work and graphviz was installed with `brew install graphviz`:

1. In Intellij, click the wrench icon on the far right of the menu panel that contains the plantuml view and editor arrangement.
2. Click 'Open settings'
3. For 'Graphviz dot executable' add `/opt/homebrew/bin/dot`.
4. Click OK and restart Intellij.

This fixes the issue for me.

You can check first that you really are missing the `/opt/local/bin/dot` (or whatever path you're shown is broken) and the `/opt/homebrew/bin/dot` exists, but likely the reason is that brew put dot under its own path.

#### Option 2.

Found myself on this same thread while using Windows 11 having a similar issue. The puml and plantuml codeblocks weren't displaying the diagram in a markdown file, only codeblock-ed text. What solved it for me:

1. Go to `Settings` in Intellij,
2. on the left menu, select `Languages & Frameworks`,
3. and under it, select `Markdown`

Review the `Markdown Extensions` section. Install and enable PlantUML there. Same solution worked for Mermaid.

Comment: This works for PlantUML preview. Thanks! Any workaround to preview from Markdown as well?

Comment: It looks like brew installs everything under `/usr/local/bin` so the path will be `/usr/local/bin/dot`

Comment: you are a saviour

Comment: To preview from the bundled Markdown, create a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/dot` to wherever homebrew installed your graphviz dot executable ( find out through `which dot` on your terminal )

Comment: this should be accepted answer if the op was a mac user

Comment: In the Sonoma OS on my mac, the graphviz was installed here:
```/opt/homebrew/Cellar/graphviz/9.0.0/bin/dot```
When you paste it as a path, you must close the IntelliJ and open it again.
You can also locale your file with ```brew list graphviz``` and then search for the executable ```dot```

Answer (score 39):

Sequence diagrams and activity diagrams work out of the box.

For other types of diagrams, you need to have **Graphviz** installed (version > `2.26.3`).

1. If you don't have **Graphviz** installed - just install it.
2. If you have it installed but its version is improper - reinstall it.
3. If you have it installed in proper version but location is other than default - point to that location. You can manage that either by specifying env variable `GRAPHVIZ_DOT` containing a path to **Graphviz** executable or pointing it out directly from IntelliJ's PlantUML plugin settings.

[Here](http://plantuml.com/graphviz-dot), you can read more on how to install **Graphviz** to get along with **PlantUML**.

Btw. I solved the same problem by simply typing `sudo apt-get install graphviz` in my console - maybe would work for you as well.

Comment: I just solved this with `brew install graphviz` on my Mac and restarting IntelliJ. Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

As mentioned here https://plantuml.com/graphviz-dot

> Since version 1.2021.5, you can experimentally use PlantUML without installing Graphviz
> if you add `!pragma layout smetana` to your diagrams for the supported types. In that case, the "Smetana" engine is used instead of Graphviz

Therefore this worked for me;

```
@startuml
!pragma layout smetana
...
@enduml
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 8):

If you:

1.installed `Graphviz`

2.configured `GRAPHVIZ_DOT` env var to your `dot.exe` file
(example `D:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe`)

And you're still getting the same error: `Cannot find Graphviz1`.
You probably need to **configure the path** to the `dot.exe` **inside the Intelij settings**.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50223283/9549972) tutorial to do so.

Answer (score 3):

In case it helps someone, these are the steps to resolve the same error (`Can not find GraphViz...`) from Eclipse editor.

1. Install GraphViz on your system. Depending on your system, installation instructions are here: https://graphviz.org/download/ . For Mac (v11.6) users, it is as simple as `brew install graphviz`
2. After installation is completed, add an environment variable: `GRAPHVIZ_DOT` to point to the path of the `dot` executable. On my machine, I added this:

   `export GRAPHVIZ_DOT=/opt/homebrew/bin/dot`
3. Add path of the `dot` executable to Eclipse PlantUml preferences (`Preferences --> Plant UML --> Path to the dot executable of Graph Viz`). Screen shot given below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. First install graphviz
2. Find dot executable and put it where IntelliJ can find it

   - Windows: Add the dot executable path in the environment variables path settings
   - Linux: find the location of dot using `where dot` and if it's not in the `/opt/local/bin` you can just create a symbolink link from lets say `/usr/local/bin` by running `ln -s /usr/local/bin/dot /opt/local/bin/dot`
3. Restart IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble too...the easiest way is to install the VsCode plugin 'Markdown Preview Enhanced' and then...magically...IntelliJ works fine too!!!

Comment: Installing yet another IDE (VsCode) to fix the one you already have is far for being __the easiest way__. Plugin most likely installs necessary dependencies as [it supports importing .dot or .puml files](https://shd101wyy.github.io/markdown-preview-enhanced/#/file-imports) to your Markdown - so there's nothing __magicall__ about that.